# Does an app on the App Store have access to the Keychain when the device is locked or app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, keychain

In my test during development, the app has read/write Keychain access when the screen is locked (passcode is enabled) or app is in background.

But debug versions of apps and App Store versions are different. Does a live app on the App Store still have read/write access to the Keychain if the device is locked or app is in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the device is locked but your app was started beforehand you retain the rights

when the device is locked but your app was NOT active before (started while device is locked) you don't have the rights

Background/Foreground doesn't matter

Comment: When would the app get started while the device is locked? I can only think of notifications right now. Can you give some examples when that happens?

Comment: push/local notifications, ibeacons, gps

Comment: Hi @Daij-Djan, when you say an app is active, does being active in a previous app version count? In my situation, after an app update, the user doesn't need to open the app, but I will send push notifications to locked phones, and the users will act on the locked screen. The action handler code needs to access the keychain and I am seeing issues with that. Do you know whether the app can access the keychain under this circumstance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. But I'm afraid I don't really know. Never tried it. Sorry